# How the grab the value of textview from a UITableView on didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

When a table view is pressed, I am trying to grab the value of a textview from that table view row that has been selected as follows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    tabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    MyOrdersController *detailVC = [[MyOrdersController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"hello %@",  detailVC.shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel.text);

}
```

But im getting null value. How can I get the value of the textview in that specific row?

Comment: `MyOrdersController *detailVC = [[MyOrdersController alloc]init];`: You are creating a whole new `MyOrdersController` object. Not the one you used before where you may have put some text in its `shipmentReferenceNumberTextLabel`.

Comment: thank you...  how can i be able to sort this out?

Comment: `MyOrdersController` is supposed to be what/where in your hierarchy?

Comment: MyOrdersController object is set as a cell's tag or something ?? Has its value set already ?? or all you are trying to do is to read the text from textfield in cell put it in MyOrdersController object???

Comment: What class is your posted code in?  How is that class related to your original `MyOrdersController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the textview from selected cell subview.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (id txtView in selectedCell.subviews)
    {
        if ([txtView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
        {
            UITextView* tv = (UITextView*)txtView;
            NSString* text = tv.text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try it:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}
```